# Is this sequence strongly convergent?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, analyticity, holder-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Consider an analytic semigroup $e^{At}$ on the Hilbert space $H$, and linear operator $G:L^2(0,T;H)\to C(0,T;H)$ as
$$x(t)=Gu(t):=\int_0^te^{A(t-s)}u(s)ds$$
The question is

*If the sequence $u_n$ converges weakly to an element $u$ in $L^2(0,T;H)$; does $x_n$ converge strongly to $x$ in $C(0,T;H)$?*

Some notes:

- From analyticity of $e^{At}$, it can be shown that $x_n$ belong to $C^{0,1/2}(0,T;H)$.
- If needed, domain of $A$ can be assumed to be a compact subspace of $H$.

Comment: Are you considering a bounded operator $A$? If yes, your second statement does not make sense.

Comment: No, it is not bounded.

Comment: Okay, are there any other requirements? Self-Adjointness or something like this? Else my proposed solution will definetely not work.

Comment: Generators of analytic semigroups are usually self-adjoint

Comment: „Usually“ or „always“? The latter will definitly not hold for arbirtary spaces (in finite dimensions any matrix generates an analytic semigroup). Could you elaborate your setting?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your operator is indeed strongly continuous in this sense. It is seen by the following three steps:

**Step 1:** *The operator $G$ is bounded and linear from $L^2$ to $L^2$.*

We have $$\|Gu\|_{L^2}^2 = \int_0^T dt\; \left| \int_0^t ds\; e^{A (t-s)} u(s)\right|^2 \\ \leq \int_0^T dt\; \left( \int_0^t ds\; \|e^{A(t-s)}\|^2 \right) \cdot \left(\int_0^t ds'\; |u(s')|^2 \right) \\
\leq C(\|A\|,T)\; \|u\|^2_{L^2}$$

**Step 2:** *The operator $G$ maps continuously into the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}$*.

A simple calculation yields that the ODE
$$ Gu'(t) = A Gu(t) + u(t)$$
holds in a weak/distributional sense. It follows that $\|Gu'\|_{L^2} \leq C \|u\|_{L^2}$. Therefore, $G$ is actually a continuous operator from $L^2$ into $W^{1,2}$.

**Step 3:** In one dimension, we have the compact Sobolev embedding $W^{1,2} \hookrightarrow C^0$. Since compact maps are completely continuous, that is they map weakly converging sequences onto strongly converging ones, we obtain that $G$ is a strongly continuous operator from $L^2$ into $C^0$.

Comment: Step 2 is vague, which seems to be the main step. Step 3 is stated for one dimensional functions. In general, for a $H$-valued function, the stated embedding is not obvious.

Comment: Yes, I suppressed some facts about Step 2. The fact that $Gu(t) = e^{At} \int_0^T \; ds u(s)$ is weakly differentiable follows from the fact that it is a product of a smooth functions and a Sobolev function (primitive integrals of $L^2$-functions are $W^{1,2}$-functions).

Comment: And for the $H$-valuedness you are right. I missed that fact. Give me a moment to think about how I can extend my answer to that case. However, with "one dimension" I am talking about the dimension of the base space, which is in this case the interval.